# Including react-native-maps package in the project is making the app crash

Tags: react-native

Running react native app on the android simulator. 
Installed react-native-maps module and build again. The app stopped working.
Build successful but the app crashes as soon as I open it without any error or exception.
google-services version 4.0.1
React native - latest

I tried adding disablestrictVersioncheck to true in the build.gradle file. Did not help.

Comment: Did you link the library using react-native link? Also: check the installation instructions since you also need a Google maps API key for Android

Comment: Yes I did, can't find a place to add the API key